# GTM not firing DOM and Window Loaded triggers

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I recently added a dataLayer on our product and checkout pages for Google Analytics enhanced ecommerce, following the conventions found on Simo's blog.  However, something strange has happened since we've added the dataLayer - the gtm.load and gtm.dom calls are no longer firing.

If I do a hard refresh, clear my cookies and go through the flow one time, everything seems to fire properly. However, once I go back to home page or some other part of the site, I only see the gtm.js getting fired and none of my triggers work.

For example, the navigation flow is home page -> product listing -> product detail.  The site is a React single page app so I have a history event trigger to fire GA tags.  If I'm a new user, and I go through those 3 pages, I will see the following fire in the dataLayer (as expected): gtm.js, gtm.dom, gtm.load, gtm.history.  However, if I go back to the home page and go through the flow again, the gtm.dom and gtm.load dataLayer objects disappear and as a result my GTM triggers never fire.  See images below for examples of what the dataLayer looks like on the product detail page for the above flow.

I'm at a loss here as I've never seen gtm.load not fire

[image: dataLayer before - working]

[image: dataLayer after - not working]

Data Layer code on product listing page:
    
    var window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []

```
dataLayer.push({
   'ecommerce': {
     'currencyCode':'CAD',
     'impressions': [    //the array of products present within the listing
      {  'id':'123456',    // Product SKU
         'name':'GOOD FOOD',    // Product Name
         'price':'7.20',   // Display price - use only xxxx.xx formatting
         'brand':'No Name', // Product Brand
         'category':'Food', 
         'position':0,    // Product position within the list
         'list':'Products page'    // leave as is    
      }, {   //second product
         'id':'456890',
         'name':'ABC Nuts',
         'price':'8.50',
         'brand':'ABC',
         'category':'Food',
         'position':1,
         'list':'Products  page'
      },

     ...

      {
         'id':'1001010',
         'name':'Fish Oil',
         'price':'95.00',
         'brand':'Zenn',
         'category':'Oil',
         'position':21,
         'list':'Products page'
      }
    ]
  }
}); </script>
```

dataLayer on Product Detail Page:

```
<script>
var window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []

dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'detail',
        'ecommerce' : { 'detail' : 
           { 'products' : [{
                 'name': 'Product ABC',      // Full product name
                 'id': '123456',   // Product SKU
                 'price': '15.25',  // Price
                 'brand': 'Noname',  // Brand of product
                 'category': 'Food', // Product category: Oil, Capsule, Flower or Accessory
                 'variant': '5g' // Size
            }]              
           }
         }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you initializing something or resetting the value of the datalayer on the homepage? Can you post code related to how you've implemented GA on the homepage and code related to history triggers?

Comment: I've pasted the dataLayer code on product listings and product detail pages.  There is no custom dataLayer being set on home page, just standard GTM snippet with GA

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in a SPA, gtm.load and gtm.dom will only happen once,  you need to base your triggers on something else.

Comment: I should clarify - only the purchase flow is SPA, the rest of site is standard pageview based - and even on regular pages I am not seeing dom and load

Comment: Are you able to paste a link? What tags do you have in GTM? What are the triggers?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194442/gtm-not-firing-dom-and-window-loaded-triggers